# Split column by specific string upon Importhtml in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Right now I have a query that pulls with the following function:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("myurl", "table", 0),"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 OFFSET 0", 1)
```

Col2 pulls in a name with their job position:

```
John Doe Accounting Team
Jane Doe Accounting Team
Josh Doe Marketing Division
Johnathan Wade Sales Team
Jake Johnson Customer Support
```

What I am after is the having the column split into two columns upon import like this:

```
John Doe III | Accounting Team
Jane Doe | Accounting Team
Josh Johnny Doe | Marketing Division
Johnathan Wade | Sales Team
Jake Johnson | Customer Support
```

I DO have the position strings that I can manually input such as "Accounting Team", "Marketing Division", "Sales Team", and "Customer Support".

I have tried a few different splits in this function but have been unable to get anything to work. I get circular calculation errors. Turning them on doesn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried using regex rather than split methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RegEx`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) should help you:

Sample formula:

`=FILTER(REGEXREPLACE(A:A,REGEXEXTRACT(A:A," "&JOIN("| ",listOfPositions)),""),A:A<>"")`

[image]

- you need a list of positions on a separate range.
- adds spaces to replace a space before the position
- `regexextract` finds the correct position to replace
- "|" pipeline is for OR logic in [regex syntax.](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)
- try `=FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A," "&JOIN("| ",listOfPositions)),A:A<>"")` to get the list of positions
- You can't get this with a `query`, the `SQL` in G-Sheets is limited and does not support `Regex`.

Comment: Very compact and well explained -- elegant.

Comment: This works great to separate the names out. I am however hoping to find a formula that will also list the position next to the name as well. So in your example, it would show the position for each person in column C. Judging by your formula this should be too difficult for me to figure out, but thought I would mention this to have a complete solution for the question at hand.

Comment: Also, would you be able to confirm there is no way to do this directly in the import query as opposed to requiring a reference to the imported data?

Comment: I defer to @Max Makhrov on whether it could be done in the query itself. Once you have a name in B1, column C could be =right(A2,len(A2)-len(B2)-1), which presumably could be made into an array formula or dragged down.

Comment: `=FILTER(REGEXREPLACE(A:A,REGEXEXTRACT(A:A," "&JOIN("| ",listOfPositions)),""),A:A<>"")` for positions, not possible with `query`

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches I see, and I am assuming the data is not pathological (e.g., if there were jobs in teams "Grip" and "Key Grip", we could only guess what to do with "Frances Scott Key Grip"). The unifying tack is the same. Find the team. Everything else is the name. I will put the team first, but it could be reversed.
Let us suppose the QUERY result sit in D18. One could, in theory, build up really long, undebuggable expressions with the QUERY embedded in them, but I think it is better to just work with the results from the query column, hiding it later if it really bugs you.
Case 1) In your example, all teams have two words. If that pattern holds up, the following will work. The team is, say in E18,

`=textjoin(" ",true,index(split(D18, " "),-1+len(split(D18, " "))),index(split(D18, " "),len(split(D18, " "))))`

where honestly textjoin and skipping blank words is probably overkill. [Instead you could take the first word & " " & the second word]. Those two index functions are grabbing the second-to-last word and the last word resulting from the split.
And clinch with in F18

`=left(D18,len(D18)-len(E18)-1)`

, where you are grabbing the beginning words but not the space after them.

Case 2) Suppose we cannot count on the two-word thing. Then let us put your 4 teams  in A1, B1, C1, and D1, say. Here, I have the query result in E2, but of course that can be changed. In F2 you put the following slightly awkward expression:

```
=if(right(E2,len($A$1))=$A$1,A1,if(right(E2,len($B$1))=$B$1,$B$1,if(right(E2,len($C$1))=$C$1,$C$1,if(right(E2,len($D$1))=$D$1,$D$1,""))))
```

which will pick off the matching team. Then clinch as above in G2 with

```
=left(E2,len(E2)-len(F2)-1)
```

These formulas can be dragged down or built into array formulas as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(B6:),SPLIT(B1:B,char(10)),))
```

The result could be positioned in any column just amend the column letter